# c++ undefined reference to `vtable with virtual classes

Tags: c++, game-engine

Every suggestion I read to fix this problem say to create a body for the deconstructor, however, I am providing my own deconstructor function.  My problem is this, I have classes in separate namespaces, I am using a purely virtual class as a base class for another.  The program will only compile if I take a pointer to the MyScene variable.  I need to pass a reference to Engine::Engine::run() or I get a segmentation fault.

------Base Class ------

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H
namespace Engine {
namespace Renderer {

class Scene
{
    public:
        virtual void create() = 0;
        virtual void destroy() = 0;
        virtual void update(double delta) = 0;
    protected:
    private:
};
} /* namespace Core */
} /* namespace Engine */
#endif // SCENE_H
```

----- MyScene.h-----

```
#ifndef MYSCENE_H_
#define MYSCENE_H_

#include "../Engine/Renderer/Scene.h"

namespace Game{
class MyScene : public ::Engine::Renderer::Scene {
public:
    void create();
    void update(double delta);
    void destroy();
};

}
#endif /* MYSCENE_H_ */
```

-----MyScene.cpp-----

```
#include "MyScene.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace Game {


void create()
{
    std::cout << "Scene Created!" << std::endl;
}

void destroy()
{
    std::cout << "Scene Destroyed!" << std::endl;
}

void update()
{
    std::cout << "Scene Updated!" << std::endl;
}


} /* namespace Game */
```

-----Main Function-------

```
#include "Engine/Engine.h"
#include "Game/MyScene.h"

int main() {

    Engine::Renderer::Window window(720, 640, false, "Test");
    Game::MyScene scene;

    return Engine::Engine::run(window, &scene);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't yet provided the definition of functions you intend to override. For example you need to add:

```
void MyScene::create()
{
    std::cout << "Scene Created!" << std::endl;
}
```

Do this for all the member functions.

`void create()` that you have written does not belong to any class and is a non-member function within `Game` namespace.

Comment: I am, apparantly a dummy...  thank you, i think this proves its time for bed.  Adding the class scope fixes this..

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting error is definitions like:-

```
void create() {}
```

You should use this in class scope like:-

```
void MyScene::create() {}
```

Please make sure you do it for all member functions.

Along with that change definition of update to accept an argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you derive a class from the abstract class all the abstract methods of your abstract class should be defined in you derived class. You didn't even define a method. When you are defining outside the class, use class scope to defining methods and make sure you have overrided all the methods that are abstract in your base class.

Don't forget, it is void update(double delta); not simply void update();